# Migration to VPS w/Plesk

Tags: migration, http-status-code-404, vps, plesk

I had a shared hosting package with 1and1 and I just moved over to their VPS hosting that uses Plesk. I already had the domains moved over the VPS server and I already uploaded all of the files via FTP.

I talked to an agent yesterday and he helped me setup the main page on the website so that it would go to the appropriate root directory. The main website is working properly whenever I go the main domain name, however, whenever I go to website.com/blank or website.com/stuff, I receive a 404 error.

The strange part is that I see the files in Plesk file manager, I just don't know why they are not displaying properly. I didn't change anything in the migration process.

I did not change the code on any of the pages and I have contacted their customer support team a number of times, but they have been unable to resolve the issue.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to make sure that the files are associated with the correct pages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permission for the files and folder under your domain, this seems to be an issue with either your ownership or permission of the files. And if thats not the problem it could even be your .htaccess file.. make sure you have transferred your .htaccess file as well from old shared hosting to new VPS.